# Want to reduce bit size for RGB levels of an image

Tags: java, algorithm, image-processing

I want to reduce the image color quantization from 16 to 8 bit. This is my code so far. It only makes the image transparent. From what I've learnt, I'm supposed to take each individual pixel and divide by factor of bit size reduction. What am I doing wrong here?

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.io.*;
    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class ConvertImage{
        public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{
            BufferedImage image = null;
            File f = null;

            try {

                       f = new File("lennapng.png");
                         image = ImageIO.read(f);
                       }catch(IOException e){
                         System.out.println(e);
                       }

                     //get width and height
                     int width = image.getWidth();
                     int height = image.getHeight();


                     width = image.getWidth();
                     height = image.getHeight();
                     for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                         for(int x = 0; x <height; x++) {
                             int p = image.getRGB(x, y);
                           // System.out.println("rgb "+ rgb);

                              int a = (p>>24) & 0xff;
                              int r = (p>>16) & 0xff;
                              int g = (p>>8) & 0xff;
                              int b = p&0xff;


                              r= r*16/256;
                              g= g*16/256;
                              b = b*16/256;

                                //set new RGB
                              p = (a<<12) | (r<<8) | (g<<4) | b;

                              image.setRGB(x, y, p);

                                        }
                    }

                      try{
                         f = new File("output.png");
                         ImageIO.write(image, "png", f);
                       }catch(IOException e){
                         System.out.println(e);
                       }


                  } 



               }
```

Comment: In a BufferedImage R,G,B,A are each 8 bit, so were are the 16 bit you want to quantify to 8 bit? Your code looks more like 8Bit -> 4Bit. But you cannot change the number of Bits per color in a BufferedImage https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#setRGB(int,%20int,%20int)

Comment: It doesn't look like you told the underlying image you wanted to change the bit depth. You just divided the values and created a new 32-bit ARGB value with the levels stuffed into the rightmost 16 bits and set that as the color of each pixel.  So A and R are now ZERO, with G and B being some meaningless combination of bits.

Comment: Notice too 0<<8 instead of r<<8. But color reduction goes differently.

Comment: the r set to 0 was a typo. so what should be my approach here?

Comment: The values `a`, `r`, `g`, `b` you read are 8-bit values by the way you read them (you extract exactly 8 bits from the integer `p`). I have no idea what is returned by `getRGB` but it probably is already 8 bits per channel. That said, if you manage to read in 16-bit R, G and B values, and you want to reduce them to 8-bits, you need to divide by 256 (right shift by 8 bits) to keep only the most important 8 bits of each value.

Comment: approach?? you dont have a problem

Comment: @gpasch the code isn't working. it only makes the image transparent.

Comment: you want to reduce pixels fine - but it wont display - if you want to reduce the pixels and store in some file fine - the image is 24 bits you cant change that, unless you go to a GRAY scale which is another chapter - so give an example what you want to achieve